# Is it possible to install localhost server in one pc and to access on multiple computers on a same network.?

Tags: xampp, localhost

We are building php web application while i am a designers and my friend is developer we work on different pcs we want to test the file by runnig on localhost on both of our pc how can we reach it. I have gone through some of concepts in internet but didn't get proper info.

Comment: Run `ifconfig(linux)` or `ipconfig(windows)` command, and give your friends the IP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to create a firewall rule to allow access through whatever port you are serving on, probably 8080.

Here is how to [create an inbound port rule in windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/access-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-inbound-port-rule)

Then they should be able to access your server by simply using your ip